Mathematical expression for the free vector space product
In the construction of the tensor product, I see the expression
$$F = A^{\oplus(M \times N)}=\bigoplus_{M\times N} A,$$
which I guess is a free module constructed by as many copies of $A$ as $M \times N$, where $A$ is a ring, and $M,N$ are modules.
Since rings are more general structures than fields, and the same for modules and vector spaces, but there is a parallelism, if I think of the most common case of the field of real numbers, is the expression saying that each vector space $\widetilde M, \widetilde N$ corresponds to $\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n$ and that the free vector space product is the same idea but with the exponent being the direct sum as in $\mathbb R^{\oplus m x n}$?

The structure in question is the free module over the set $M\times N$. The module structure on $M\times N$ is irrelevant for its definition. As in the case of vector spaces, this can be constructed as the set of all $(a_i)_{i\in M\times N}\in A^{M\times N}$ with $a_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i$. This can also be written as $\bigoplus_{i\in M\times N}A$.

is the expression saying that each vector space $\widetilde M, \widetilde N$ corresponds to $\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n$

Not exactly sure what you mean by that, but, unlike vector spaces, not every module is free, so this line of thinking is probably wrong. And also, the module structure on $M\times N$ does not matter for the definition of the free module over $M\times N$, as I mentioned above.

Okay. Yes, that's what the lecturer mentioned: the free module. You made it more precise, perhaps helping up to people who already know the topic. And yes, I'm sure I was wrong, otherwise why would I subject myself to this by asking the question.

$$F = A^{\oplus(M \times N)}=\bigoplus_{M\times N} A$$
$$F =\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x_i,y_i) \mid a_i\in A, x_i\in M,y_i\in N, n\geq1\right\}$$
is the set of linear combinations of elements of $M\times N$ with coefficients in $A.$
